# Haskell: Attempt at parallel `atomicModifyIORef` implementation

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ioref

From what I understand, modifications to `IORef`s are very quick, all they involve is updating a thunk pointer. Of course, the reader (i.e. someone who wants to see the value on their webpage) will then need to take time to evaluate these thunks (which may build up if writers are not reading back the results).

I was thinking it would be good to start actually evaluating the modification thunks on the `IORef` in parallel, since in many circumstances they'll probably have to be evaluated at some point anyway (obviously, this will break with infinite data structures).

So I've wrote the following function, with a similar signature to `atomicModifyIORef`:

```
atomicModifyIORefPar :: (NFData a) => IORef a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> IO b
atomicModifyIORefPar ioref f =
  let 
    g olddata = 
      let (newdata, result) = f olddata in (newdata, (result, newdata))
  in do
    (result, newdata) <- atomicModifyIORef ioref g
    force newdata `par` return result
```

This seems to work ([test code here](http://pastebin.com/zVeWsKUM)). Is there anything I've done wrong here? Or is there a better way to do this?

---

**Edit: Second attempt**

Inspired by [Carl's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213089/525980). We actually store `force newdata` into the `IORef`. This is the same as `newdata` anyway, but shows the runtime that we want to keep `force newdata` for later, so it doesn't garbage collect the spark.

```
atomicModifyIORefPar :: (NFData a) => IORef a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> IO b
atomicModifyIORefPar ioref f =
  let 
    g olddata = 
      let 
        (newdata, result) = f olddata
        newdata_forced = force newdata
      in 
        (newdata_forced, (result, newdata_forced))
  in do
    (result, newdata_forced) <- atomicModifyIORef ioref g
    newdata_forced `par` return result
```

Comment: Looks good to me, but somehow I would expect `MVar` instead of `IORef` when atomicity matters.

Comment: Can't you define IORef strict ? like IORef !Bla

Comment: @VagifVerdi: Wouldn't that slow down writers, also locking the `IORef` until the modify function is calculated?

Comment: @Clinton. I don't think so. It only evaluates to HNF (head normal form). Besides the only way to know for sure is to benchmark.

Comment: @VagifVerdi No, you can only add strictness annotations to the value constructor, not to the type constructor. And the value constructor for IORef is hidden. (Not to mention Clinton's objection, which would be valid even if that was possible.)

Comment: @Carl: Data Bla = Bla ![Foo]; IORef Bla. Would this work ?

Comment: @VagifVerdi No. The Bla would be strict in its contents, but the IORef wouldn't be strict in its. So when you operate on the IORef, you get unevaluated thunks refering to a Bla. Evaluating one of those also causes all its strict arguments to be evaluated at the same time - but not before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not work, depending on the version of GHC. The spark pool's interaction with GC has been variable throughout history. In some versions, the fact that the expression `force newdata` isn't referred to by anything in scope after `atomicModifyIORefPar` returns means that it's likely to be garbage collected before the spark created by `par` ever is converted, which means that the spark will also be collected.

Other versions of GHC have treated the spark pool as roots in GC analysis, but that has problems too. I don't remember what the current state is, but I suspect it's that the spark pool does not count as GC roots. The problems it raises (loss of parallelism when the returned expressions don't refer to the expressions being evaluated in parallel) are less bad than the problems created by treating the spark pool as GC roots (retaining memory that isn't needed).

---

**Edit - second attempt at answering**

This new implementation looks right, for the reasons you give. The expression being evaluated in parallel is also reachable from the GC roots.

Comment: Could you comment on my proposed solution in the edited question above?